# How to create a dynamic UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, uiimageview

I want to create an UIImageView with, for example, "Trend.jgp" for a special case (if-condition). I tried various ways with CGRectMake but I am not able to create this picture dynamically to a special place. Furthermore, I can't use the function setimage like it's described in the Developer Documentation.

Has anyone got an idea how to realise my plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Trend"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(....) or  imageView.center = CGPointMake(...)
```

Add this view to your container view, i.e. `[myView addSubview:imageView];`

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imageView = nil;
if (specialCase) {
  imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"Trend.jpg"]];
} else {
  //whatever you want to do in the other case
}
```